# Springfox : Short type is considered as $int32

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

**Language**

- Java / Springboot / Springfox[ 2.9.2]

**Description**

Hi, i'm using springfox-swagger-ui and springfox-bean-validators
How can i tell to swagger that my property is a Short ($int16)

**My Pojo**

```
    @ApiModelProperty(required = true, dataType = "java.lang.Short")
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("deviceId")
    private Short deviceId;
```

**The result in Swagger**

`deviceId* | integer($int32)`

**Expected**

`deviceId* | $int16`

Thanks a lot

Cordially

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't.

[Swagger specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md) does not support `short` (`int16`) data type.

**Supported data types**:

```
+-------------+---------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Common Name |  type   |  format   |                     Comments                     |
+-------------+---------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------+
| integer     | integer | int32     | signed 32 bits                                   |
| long        | integer | int64     | signed 64 bits                                   |
| float       | number  | float     |                                                  |
| double      | number  | double    |                                                  |
| string      | string  |           |                                                  |
| byte        | string  | byte      | base64 encoded characters                        |
| binary      | string  | binary    | any sequence of octets                           |
| boolean     | boolean |           |                                                  |
| date        | string  | date      | As defined by full-date - RFC3339                |
| dateTime    | string  | date-time | As defined by date-time - RFC3339                |
| password    | string  | password  | Used to hint UIs the input needs to be obscured. |
+-------------+---------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I'll keep this link in my favorites.